# Specifying the Error Ratio in Deming Regression

Tags: standard-error, method-comparison, total-least-squares

We use Deming Regression for method validation in our clinical ELISA laboratory. As we run clinical trials this needs to be performed if we get a new reagent batch, batch of plates, new plate reader or a new operator etc.

An important part of Deming Regression is calculating the error ratio which is the ratio of the standard deviations for x and y; SDx and SDy. I can't find any information on how to derive these.

Obviously I know how to calculate the standard deviation but what data can one use for this? For example, if we buy a new instrument that reads the ELISA plates, we would run a selection of samples with a wide range of values and then compare the old and new instrument by Deming Regression to make sure they give comparable results. How do I know what the standard deviation is for each instrument and thus specify the error ratio?

I can provide references if required.

Comment: Repeatedly measure the same object multiple times and compute SD?

Comment: That seems very reasonable. The only issue is that it becomes extremely time consuming doing something like that with ELISA (as opposed to an automated analyser for example).

But I suppose that's the only option, right?

Comment: Well, maybe the company that produces the device can provide some estimates of the uncertainties. Check the manual.

Comment: I'm wondering if simply running measurements the measurements in replicates would be sufficient? The reason it's got me thinking is because ELISAs involve both human (pipetting) error and measurement/instrument error.

Comment: Fair enough. You need to repeat the whole pipeline, pipetting included. Unless you can assume that one error is much smaller than the other.

Answer (score 0):

For reasons I don't understand Dr. Mack uses the ratio of the variances.  This is makes the Deming regression the same as a Geometric-Mean regression:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kXzzlueX3tw&t=900s

https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1742-6596/78/1/012084/pdf   <-- section 2.4

This solution evidently goes back to a 1935 paper by Dent:

DENT, B.M.; "On observation of points connected by a linear relation" Proc. Phys. Soc. 1935

A publicly available explanation is given here (equation 1.4.12):
https://pure.tue.nl/ws/portalfiles/portal/4259628/7802107.pdf

Jansen, J., & Barrett, J. F. (1978). On the theory of maximum likelihood estimation of structural relations. Part 1: One dimensional case. (EUT report. E, Fac. of Electrical Engineering; Vol. 78-E-78). Technische Hogeschool Eindhoven.

Ling Leng et al 2007 J. Phys.: Conf. Ser. 78 012084
DOI 10.1088/1742-6596/78/1/012084

Comment: Hi, welcome to CV! Please add references for your links in case they die in the future. And if possible, summarize their content a bit. Link-only answers are deleted on this site.

Comment: Antoine, Thanks for gently informing me of the rules.  I added a citation for the second link, but the first one is an online course that is a little tricky to cite.  I'll keep this in mind for future answers.